# Hide page elements using jquery user agent detection slow in Android but not iOS - how to fix?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, css

I am using a service called GoNative to make an iOS and Android app out of my website at https://www.nikoncafe.com

GoNative apps allow for user agent detection as discussed here: http://support.gonative.io/knowledge_base/topics/how-do-i-detect-usage-coming-from-my-apps?from_search=true

I am using the following jQuery to hide certain page elements when visitors are using the apps as opposed to their mobile browsers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/gonative/i)) {
    $('#QuickSearchPlaceholder').hide();
    $('.xbOffCanvasControls').hide();
};
});
</script>
```

On the iOS app, this works well.  Those elements are hidden.  However on the Android app, they show for a moment before they are hidden.  Is there a way to prevent that?  Can I preload the code to make it hide faster (before they show)?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

By default .hide() has a duration of 400ms. You can use "fast" or a ms value inside .hide() to speed things up:

```
$('#QuickSearchPlaceholder').hide(0);
$('.xbOffCanvasControls').hide(0);
```

Also, it may take some time before .ready() fires, so if still too slow you could try javascript without waiting for that event (assuming goNative doesn't need jquery).

Otherwise you'd have to change the logic: hide by default, and show when needed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I think it's a little faster now, but it still shows them before hiding.  I hadn't thought about changing the logice to hide by default.  That's a great idea.  I will try it.  Thanks!